# Moving a DIV one line up

Tags: html, css

Is there any CSS attribute that would move "Paul D Kelly" infront of Member. I have this requirement where i cannot add any attribute in any other DIV than the parent div of Paul D Kelly Span. i tried several display values on it but only if i give display:inline-block on both Member and Paul D Kelly div, they come in line, but i want to find out a way to bring them in line by just adding an attribute in Paul D Kelly DIV.

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:17.8pt; left:40.8pt; width:223.8pt; height:54pt; border:0pt solid black;border:1px solid red">
    
    
<div style="position:relative;width:62pt;height:15.25pt; line-height:0.5;">
<span style="white-space:pre-wrap; line-height:12pt; font:normal 10pt Helvetica; color:rgb(0,0,0)">Member:</span>
</div> 

<div style=" position:relative; left:2.16pt;width:92pt;height:12pt; line-height:0.5;">
<span style="white-space:pre-wrap; line-height:12pt; font:normal 10pt Helvetica; color:rgb(0,0,0)">PAUL D KELLEY</span>
</div> 
    
    
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/bmmey9pc/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` or `display:inline-flex`

check jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/p8nf67d5/

Comment: thanks for the answer but my problem is i can only add attribute to the "immediate parent div of PaulDKelly Span, not the parent div of all divs..

Answer (score 0):

you use `display:flex` or `display:inline-flex` on parent div

and

another case is add `float:left` to both child div

Comment: thanks, for the answer but my problem is i can only add attribute to the "immediate parent div of PaulDKelly Span, not the parent div of all divs..

Comment: use a position:relative, left:64px, top:-16px property on that div if you got a perfect answer please mark you answer! and you save a others time

Answer (score 0):

Add `top: -19px;left: 63px;` for immediate parent of span having textPAUL D KELLEY

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/p8nf67d5/5/

Comment: you have added float:left on the parent of both spans! i want to change only the parent of PaulD Kell's span!

Comment: updated above answer and jsfiddle too. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:17.8pt; left:40.8pt; width:223.8pt; height:54pt; border:0pt solid black;border:1px solid red">


    <div style="position: relative; width: 62pt; height: 15.25pt; line-height: 0.5; display: inline;">
    <span style="white-space:pre-wrap; line-height:12pt; font:normal 10pt Helvetica; color:rgb(0,0,0)">Member:</span>
    </div> 

    <div style="position: relative; left: 2.16pt; width: 92pt; height: 12pt; line-height: 0.5; display: inline-block;">
    <span style="white-space: pre-wrap; font: 10pt Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); display: inline-block ! important;">PAUL D KELLEY</span>
    </div> 


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...I cannot add any attribute in any other DIV than the parent div of
>   Paul D Kelly Span...

Assuming you cannot change anything else, in that case, the only option left with you is to relatively move the `div` equal to the height of the `div` before it and give it a `left` property roughly equal to the `width` you are expecting for the label:

```
position:relative; top: -15.15pt; left: 62pt;
```

***Snippet***:

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:16pt; left:40.8pt; width:223.8pt; height:54pt; border:0pt solid black;border:1px solid red">
    <div style="position:relative;width:62pt;height:15.25pt; line-height:0.5;">
        <span style="white-space:pre-wrap; line-height:12pt; font:normal 10pt Helvetica; color:rgb(0,0,0)">Member:</span>
    </div> 
    <div style=" position:relative; top: -15.15pt; left:62pt;width:92pt;height:12pt; line-height:0.5;">
        <span style="white-space:pre-wrap; line-height:12pt; font:normal 10pt Helvetica; color:rgb(0,0,0)">PAUL D KELLEY</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/bmmey9pc/5/

***Note***: It would be better if you could move your inline styles to an externally referenced stylesheet. This would enable you to use classes and re-use the styles, and keep your code clean.